# Solution of an equation 1

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to find a real valued function $g(x)$ such that $e^{mx}-g(x)e^x=0$ for every integer $m$ and for every real $x$.

Comment: Can you solve $a-bc=0$ for b?

Comment: @Pooja, there is format to ask question here, please follow, else you will get downvotes only : http://math.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Actually  i am not able to understand where i am wrong. Please tell me clearly.

Answer (score 1):

we have $$e^{mx}-g(x)\cdot e^x=0$$ frrom here we have
$$e^{mx}=g(x)\cdot e^x$$ thus we have
$$e^{mx-x}=g(x)$$

Comment: Yes, that's the only possible function.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Put $e^x=t $ and

$g (x)=g (\ln (t))=h (t) $

we want that

$t^m-t.h (t)=0$ fror every $m $ and $t $.

if $m=1$, we get $h (t)=1$

which is not true for $m=0$.

Comment: Your sign is wrong, it should be $t^m-th(t)=0$, so the counterexample does not work.